# How to populate a ListView using an if statement?

Tags: android, listview, if-statement

Basically this is what i want to happen:

```
if (condition is met){
    //add string to listview to be displayed
}


if (condition is met){
    //remove string from listview and replace with a different string
}
```

Heres the code i have for the listview as my MainActivity.

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    clock_TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clock_TV);
    timeOfDay_TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeOfDay_TV);
    characterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.characterButton);
    updatePerSec();

  ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.inventory_list_view, inventoryCatagories);
  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: `adapter.add` would be a good start. Please show your code as a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If you are manipulating the data behind your list view your best approach would be to do all the data filtering before populating. If you need to change the data after it is rendered then remember to call `notifydatasetchanged` on your adapter

Comment: Im wanting to add to, amd remove from the listview at random intervals AND when the user does certain things in the app. For instance,  if the user presses a button,  the list view removes the item that was added firstly,  and replaces it with another random string

Comment: You are still going to be better off manipulating the array behind the list then calling `notifydatasetchanged`. Otherwise you are going to run the risk of your views getting out of sync with your driving data set.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a RecylerAdapter with the list view here is what happens and why it happens the items in the ListView are bound to a view holder and if an item is added the Recyleradapter updates the ListView and if an item is deleted the RecyclerAdapter updates the List View We will post code for a ListActivity first then the code for the RecyclerAdapter not sure where your data comes from outs is in a SQLite DB

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DBHelper helper;
static List<DBModel>dbList;
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private static RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

    addListenerOnButtonAdd();
    TextView tvNoData = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvNoData);

    setTitle("");// This sets the title of the toolbar
    Toolbar topToolBar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(topToolBar);
    //topToolBar.setLogo(R.drawable.keyss);// See Notes in MainActivity

    setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    // Line of code above is used when you navigate back from DetailsActivity with
    // soft keyboard visible on DA IT WILL NOT BECOME VISIBLE ON ListActivity
    // Data Entry NOT required in ListActivity
    // also SEE settings in Styles for this issue;


    helper = new DBHelper(this);
    dbList = new ArrayList<>();
    dbList = helper.getDataFromDB();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // Code below defines the adapter
    mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this,dbList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    int sz = dbList.size();
    if(sz == 0){/* No Data in DB let the user know better than a Toast or Blank Screen*/
        tvNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvNoData.setText("No Data");
    }
}

// This method is called from DetailsActivity and notifies Recycler View that the DB was changed
// and the method makes the same changes to the Recycler View kind of a sync of DB and Recycler View
public static void removeListRow(int position) {
    dbList.remove(position);
    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, dbList.size());
}

/* this BUTTON is on the ToolBar click to ADD new record */
private void addListenerOnButtonAdd() {
    // Navigate to DetailsActivity to ADD new DATA
    Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
    setSupportActionBar( tb );

    tb.findViewById( R.id.btnAdd ).setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentSP = new Intent(ListActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class );
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("FROM_LIST_ACTIVITY","true" );
            intentSP.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity( intentSP );
        }
    } );
}

public void onBackPressed(){
    Intent intent = new Intent( ListActivity.this, MainActivity.class );
    startActivity( intent );
}
```

}

RecyclerAdapter

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

static List<DBModel> dbList;
static private Context context;
int sz;

RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<DBModel> dbList) {

    RecyclerAdapter.dbList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerAdapter.context = context;
    RecyclerAdapter.dbList = dbList;
}

@Override
public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);
    // create ViewHolder
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);

    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.rowid.setText(String.valueOf(dbList.get(position).getRowid()));
    holder.station.setText(dbList.get(position).getStation_Name());
    System.out.println("RecyclerAdapter BindViewHolder FIRST position "+position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dbList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView station, rowid;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);

        rowid = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rvROWID);
        station = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.rvSTATION);
        // Attach a click listener to the entire row view
        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

   @Override // When an item in DetailsActivity is touched (selected) the RecyclerView has
    //  a OnClickListener attached in the above Code that implements the method below
    public void onClick(View v) {

       Intent intentN = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
       Bundle extras = new Bundle();
       extras.putInt("POSITION", getAdapterPosition());
       extras.putString("FROM_LIST_ACTIVITY", "false");
       intentN.putExtras(extras);
       context.startActivity(intentN);
   }
}
```